# Was double pulsar's source code ever released?

Tags: source-code, backdoor

[Double Pulsar](https://www.wired.com/beyond-the-beyond/2017/04/double-pulsar-nsa-leaked-hacks-wild/)

I can only see a binary at this address: https://github.com/x0rz/EQGRP_Lost_in_Translation

News articles seem to not discriminate between the source code and the binary